# Pull data from Bandsintown API

Tags: javascript, arrays, get

I need a little help on pulling events data from the Bandsintown API. I tested the HTTP GET request in the Postman App and it returns data correctly.

Now I am trying to pull this data into a JavaScript to then render it on a website that I design, but it seems that something does not work. Here's my code:

```
var eventRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
eventRequest.open('GET', 'https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/${artistname}/events?date=upcoming&app_id=${app_id}');
eventRequest.onload = function() {
  var eventsData = eventRequest.responseText;
};
eventRequest.send();
```

To render the data further down in the JS I am using:

```
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
   ${eventsData.map(eventTemplate).join("")}
`;
```

Comment: chances are, that eventsData hasn't been populated by the **asynchronous** callback in onload ... rather than having that code "further down", put it **inside** the onload callback, where the data **is available** ... note `var eventsData` inside the `onload` callback certainly won't be available anywhere except in that function where it is declared - that's how variables work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1):

you can try this and in log might see further error.

```
var eventRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

eventRequest.open("GET", "https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/${artistname}/events?date=upcoming&app_id=${app_id}", true);

eventRequest.onreadystatechange = function (event) {  
    if (eventRequest.readyState === 4) {  
        if (eventRequest.status === 200) {  
          console.log(eventRequest.responseText)  
        } else {  
           console.log("Error", eventRequest.statusText);  
        }  
    }  
}; 

eventRequest.send(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, I'm pretty sure that if you want to use string literals in your url (${artistname}) you will need back quote (``) instead of simple or double-quotes.

```
'https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/${artistname}/events?date=upcoming&app_id=${app_id}'
```

to

```
`https://rest.bandsintown.com/artists/${artistname}/events?date=upcoming&app_id=${app_id}`
```